# Trying to get the number of the month before of the current month

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to get the number of month before of the current month (now is `04` (april), so I'm trying to get `03`). I'm trying this:

```
date('m')-1;
```

but I get `3`. But what I want is to get `03`.

Comment: *(hint)* `date` formats a date to a string. When using arithmetics on a string, the string is converted to integer. you should be able to figure out the rest now.

Comment: you cannot use this way. think of `january` for example... `1-1 is 0` not december (`12`)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The correct way to do this really is:

`date('m', strtotime('-1 month'));`

As you will see strange things happen in January with other answers.

Comment: It will be fine @ january?

Comment: The problem with this is that with for instance month `March` it'll bring `03` not `3`

Comment: Change the **m** to **n** if you need month without the zero. `date('n', strtotime('-1 month'));` - [Source](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: actually this can cause Errors if used on the 31 of a month. You should use date("n", strtotime("first day of previous month"));  instead

Answer (score 4):

The currently accepted response will result in an incorrect answer whenever the day of the month (for the current day) is a larger number than the last day of the month for the previous month.

e.g. The result of executing `date('m', strtotime('-1 month'));` on March 29th (in a non-leap-year) will be 03, because 29 is larger than any day of the month for February, and thus `strtotime('-1 month')` will actually return March 1st.

Instead, use the following:

```
date('n') - 1;
```

Comment: yes correct, but this will return 0 on january... 
date("n", strtotime("first day of previous month")); is a good way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You may be surprised, but [date() function manual page](http://php.net/date) has an exact example of what you need:

```
$lastmonth = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")-1, date("d"), date("Y"));
```

Comment: Where is the exact example? I can't readily see it. The link just goes through to the top of the man page.

Comment: @Treffynnon there is an example of getting a timestamp of the last month. though, formatting is left for your homework, yeah

Comment: I think this is the line you mean `$lastmonth = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")-1, date("d"),   date("Y"));`. @Glebushka method is easier to read in my opinion.

Comment: My be. But mktime is way more flexible than this strtotime crutch. And my point was, if you didn't notice, that the answer is present on the manual page, so, you need no Glebushka to get your answer at all.

Answer (score 0):

The result of your calculation is a number. If you want to format it like a string, you can use:

```
$result = date('m')-1;
$string_result = sprintf("%02s", $result);
```

**Edit:** Note that this is only a partial solution to format a number like a string.

Comment: -1 I'm not sure this is a good solution. date('m') returns 04, and then you take 04-1=3. But what happens with Jan 01-1=0??? It is better to create a modified date with strtotime and then syntax it with date.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, @Johan You are right, it´s only a solution to format a number like a string. I´ve edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: `$result = ((date('m')-1) ?: 12)`.  There.  January -> December is accounted for.

Answer (score 0):

```
intval(date('m'))
```

for the current month

```
(intval(date('m'))-1)%12
```

for the previous month, also for december/january

Answer (score 0):

```
date('m', strtotime('last month'));
```

This will work regardless of whether or not you're in January

Answer (score -1):

This works too.

```
printf("%02s", (date('m') - 1));
```

Comment: reading other answers before starting your own works even better

Answer (score -2):

This should do it for you...

```
str_pad(date('m')-1,  2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```